# Resize image PIL не сохраняя пропорций

Tags: python, python-3.x, pil, pillow

PIL почему-то сохраняет пропорции, что я делаю не так?

*//Проверял в обозревателе пропорции реально сохранены, вывод верный*
[image: мяу]

```
image = "image.jpg"
result = 'greyscale.png'
size = (28,28)
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(image).convert('LA')
img.thumbnail((size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save(result)
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename = result, width=400)
```

Comment: А почему он не должен их сохранять? В документации про thumbnail прямым текстом написано, что сохраняет.

Comment: тогда я хоть убей не пойму почему ВЕЗДЕ указывается и высота и долгота, хотя достаточно в таком случае указать что то одно.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Потому что можно указать неодинаковые ширину и высоту — картинка сожмётся так, чтобы ширина и высота получились не больше указанных